# Ruby RVM gives me version 2.0 but Bundler says I'm incorrectly running version 2.3

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am just starting to work on an old Ruby Rails project. The Gemfile specifies:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
```

I am running a new version of Ubuntu, which I think came with Ruby 2.3 as the default. So I install RVM and then I:

```
rvm --default use 2.0.0
ruby -v
```

which gives me:

```
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-linux]
```

then I run:

```
bundle install
```

and I get this error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

How do I get RVM to enforce the correct version of Ruby?

Comment: What is the output of `which bundle`? Perhaps you're not running it through `rvm`? Maybe you need to `gem install bundler`?

Comment: As always, check `which bundler` and `which ruby` and so on to see which in your `PATH` are being engaged.